# Get hostname in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, hostname

I've got a JQuery function using getJSON to bring some userifo. It's like that:

```
$.getJSON("http://server.com/?apirequested=userinfo", function(data){
   ...
   ...
});
```

This works fine, but I'm trying to change it to use same code for several servers using relatives url's.

I'm trying several things like:

```
$.getJSON($(location).attr('hostname')+"/?apirequested=userinfo" ...
```

or

```
$.getJSON($(location).attr('protocol')+$(location).attr('hostname')+"/?apirequested=userinfo",
```

or

```
$.getJSON(location.hostame+"/?apirequested=userinfo" ...
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Have you read any documentation for [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)?

Comment: **…accessible via Document.location and Window.location respectively…**. By the way, `location` interface has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: why doesn't `$.getJSON(location.host+"/?apirequested=userinfo"` work?

Answer (score 4):

This might be help you.

http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/get-current-url-javascript-jquery

```
$(location).attr('host');                        www.test.com:8082
$(location).attr('hostname');                    www.test.com
$(location).attr('port');                        8082
$(location).attr('protocol');                    http:
$(location).attr('pathname');                    index.php
$(location).attr('href');                        http://www.test.com:8082/index.php#tab2
$(location).attr('hash');                       #tab2
$(location).attr('search');                     ?foo=123
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It works with:

```
$.getJSON($(location).attr('protocol')+"//"+$(location).attr('hostname')+"/?apirequested=userinfo", ...
```

Comment: Why not just `location.protocol` and `location.hostname `instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
let myurl = location.protocol+"//"+location.hostname+"/?apirequested=userinfo";
$.getJSON(myurl);
```

or perhaps simpler

```
let myurl = location.origin + "/?apirequested=userinfo";
$.getJSON(myurl);
```